# Table of links in Word document are referring document itself instead headers after emailing text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have long text in Word document with table of contents. When i copy whole text (Ctrl + a, Ctrl + c) and paste it to a new email (Ctrl + v) and send it (with Outlook as Html-message) toc links are not working anymore. Links are referring original document instead anchors (headings) on same document. Links are not affected if i send same content using Thunderbird.

I am using Word 2016. Using Word 2010 and Outlook 2010 links are working ok on recipient email. What is wrong with that 2016 version?

Comment: Do you mean Hyperlinks in Table in a word documents changed? Pointing to a different address?  When pasting, do you choose “Keep Source Formatting”?

Comment: Yes. I have to try that.